# WAMP and connecting to a MIcrosoft SQL server

Tags: sql-server, wamp

So currently having an issue with WAMP and connecting to Microsoft SQL server I've tried installing all the drivers that it needs and altering the PHP.ini file in both the PHP folder and Apache but it still continues to display the following errors

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\wamp\www\Submission1.php on line 9
( ! ) PDOException: could not find driver in C:\wamp\www\Submission1.php on line 9
```

Any reason on why this is ? I've followed every tutotial possible. im using 
PHP logo
PHP Version 5.5.12

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using, and is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: it's 32 bit and the wamp server is  5.5.12

Comment: Also did you install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: ___Small Note:___ You should not be putting any of your code in the `wamp\www` folder. make a subfolder for your site(s) or better still create a Virtual Host